# Stored procedure runs when exec but doesn't run in agent job even though it's successful

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-agent-job

I've read alot of other people having similar problems but nothing I've found so far have worked. 
This is a SQL Server 2008 R2 and we have a agent job that runs once a day that fills a table with data. When running a new query and exec sp it works fine but when we run it as a agent job it completes as successful but doesn't actually fills any data when looking at most recent data by date. 
The account running sql agent is sysadmin and I've also tried running it with a SQL account with execute as user (the sql account is db_owner on the database). I've tried adding TEXTSIZE 200000 to the step. 
I've also ran a trace and by the looks of it the stored procedure actually run as intended

This is the SP:

```
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CalculateKPIs_2]    Script Date: 2019-11-20 09:06:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateKPIs_2]
AS

          -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
          -- interfering with SELECT statements.
          SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
          -- Calculate daily totals per api resource
  INSERT INTO API_TRAFFIC_SUMMARY_STAT 
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20),
       api,
             api_version,
             method, 
       resource_path,
             SUM(request_count),
             SUM(fault_count),
             MIN(min_response_time),
       SUM(request_count * avg_response_time) / SUM(request_count),
       MAX(max_response_time),
       MIN(min_service_time),
       SUM(request_count * avg_service_time) / SUM(request_count),
       MAX(max_service_time)
  FROM api_traffic_summary
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20) = convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 20)
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20), api, api_version, method, resource_path;

  -- Calculate daily totals per api resource for each application
INSERT INTO API_TRAFFIC_SUMMARY_STAT_APPLICATION 
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20),
                   user_id,
                   application_name,
                   api,
                   api_version,
                   method, 
                   resource_path,
                   SUM(request_count),
                   SUM(fault_count),
                   MIN(min_response_time),
                   SUM(request_count * avg_response_time) / SUM(request_count),
                   MAX(max_response_time),
                   MIN(min_service_time),
                   SUM(request_count * avg_service_time) / SUM(request_count),
                   MAX(max_service_time)
  FROM api_traffic_summary
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20) = convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 20)
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20), user_id, application_name, api, api_version, method, resource_path;

-- Calculate daily fault totals per api resource for each application
INSERT INTO API_FAULT_SUMMARY_STAT_APPLICATION 
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20),
                   user_id,
                   application_name,
                   api,
                   api_version,
                   method, 
                   resource_path,
                   endpoint_address,
                   error_code,
                   SUM(fault_count)
  FROM api_fault_summary
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20) = convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 20) AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND application_name IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20), user_id, application_name, api, api_version, method, resource_path, endpoint_address, error_code;
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Add try..catch block to your sp, log the error in catch and then throw it. Add logging after every statement that will write to a table the instruction and @@rowcount. This way you'll see if it writes something or not

Comment: >>>but doesn't actually fills any data when looking at most recent data by date<<< If  the login has another default language your job inserts other dates than you expect. It's not a correct way to check if something was inserted

Comment: @sepupic regarding looking at recent data, I run order by request_date desc which show the correct date stamp if I run the SP manually though.

Comment: >>> if I run the SP manually though<<< I said it can be different because you run it under another login. date format can be different and as the result you insert other dates. What is the problem with printing @@rowcount as output or logging it to some table?

Comment: Time zones? If request_datetime is UTC comparing against getdate() could be mismatching.

Comment: Yeah I've added a @@rowcount with print on every insert statement and it actually does it's job with inserts. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

```
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    PRINT 'Something went wrong!'
ELSE PRINT 'Rows were updated...'
```

On every Insert statement and can now easily view the output in the agent job history as following:

```
    Rows were updated... 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Rows were updated... 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Rows were updated... 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0).  The step succeeded.
```

Thanks @sepupic for the help